# Is it possible to run shell script in the current shell instance not in a new one?

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I want to do something like "cd /path/to/some/folder" and after the script finishes I want to stay in that directory but instead I get back to the original directory before running the script.

After searching I read about running the script with `source` command but it's only available for linux. does Windows have something similar?

EDIT
it's a ".sh" script

Comment: Which shell are you asking about – Bash? Cmd.exe? PowerShell? You've tagged the post with [bash], but the `source` command is available for Bash regardless of OS (after all it's an internal shell command).

Comment: it's a ".sh" so I believe it's a PowerShell? I don't really know I'm so new to this.

Comment: I tried the source command again and it worked! I think it didn't work before because I was using CMD shell. thank you for your answer

Comment: Is it `.sh` because you called it so? The script is in some language that may or may not correspond to the extension. Do you choose the language? or is it imposed? Your interactive shell understands some language. Do you choose the shell? or is it imposed? You can "source" or "call" (or whatever) only a script written in a language your current shell understands. You can run any script like a program, but then (in most shells) the script cannot affect the current shell.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I know they are different but I didn't know which is better for my use case (which is running a few commands which are mostly git commands to start up a project) so I just went with `.sh`

Comment: `.sh` is typically used for Bash and/or its predecessor Bourne shell (aka /bin/sh), though those shells don't really care about the filename but it's still the usual convention. PowerShell prefers `.ps1` while Cmd.exe wants either `.bat` or `.cmd`.

Comment: I'm planning to read more about shells to understand them better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute the script w/o creating new instance you should do:

```
call script.batch
```

This will execute it in current instance and keep all the dings you did in the script.

For bash scripts you can use:

```
. ./script.sh
```

which do the same as above

Comment: it's a ".sh" script and I tried to do the call command now and it didn't work, gave me "bash: call: command not found"

Comment: @MohamedTarek Add this information to the question

Comment: I tried the ". ./script.sh" and it worked, I also tried the source command again and it also worked! I don't know why it didn't before, maybe because I was using a different shell, I'm currently running it in GIT-BASH shell and before I was running it in CMD shell

thank you so much for your answer

Comment: @MohamedTarek, `cmd` is totally different from `bash`. Work with one of them.